# Why is "many choices is" used here?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I saw a text from an article, which is given below:

[image]

I want to know that why **is** is being used here. Here the subject is "choices" then why didn't the author use "choices are"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that “choices” is not the subject of this sentence. I think something is omitted in the sentence, that’s why “is” is used here. The full sentence must be “having too many choices is not good for a young child”, where “having” is omitted; for this reason, “is” is used here. If the verb had been plural, then we would understand "choices" to be the subject.

Answer (score 0):

*Too many choices* here is a collective, single entity, thus the singular *is*. Like "Fifteen miles *is* a long distance to walk." In that text *too many choices* means "an excessive *number* of choices" which is singular. Consider the following sentence:

> Many choices *are* made by the officer every day.

Here, *each* choice is made separately, the choices are made one by one, one after another.

In your sentence it is different. A young child faces *a set, an array* of many choices from which the child is to choose something. A *cloud* of choices is before the child. That is what the author meant by choosing the singular *is* there, to show as a single entity, a *multitude* of choices from which the child is to pick just one, or maybe just a few of them.

Comment: I am confused now. Your answer is contradictory to the previous answer I received.

Comment: @Acash - Yes, it is contradictory to the previous answer because I disagree with that answer. It's all about descriptive vs. prescriptive approach. A person wrote that text about choices and the way she used the verb 'to be' (_is_) fits the general pattern of English subject-predicate agreement in number. I've just explained for you _why_ such usage is valid and what was meant by such usage.

Comment: The seemingly conflicting answers that Yellow Sky and PrinceSadh provided are simply descriptions from two different perspectives, @Acash.  Sky offers an informal, plain English description--that "too many choices" in this context represents *a singular concept*.  The verb agrees with the semantics of the subject.  Sadh explains that a formal analysis under scholastic English fails.  The verb does not agree with the form of its apparent subject.  One way to make the formal analysis work is to assume an *elision*--something like "[having] too many choices" or "[the burden of] too many choices".